# create subclass object with reference to existing object

Tags: javascript, node.js

In node.js (Javascript) I have two classes, class `mainclass` and `subclass`, where `subclass` inherites from `mainclass`.

In an other module (other class, other .js file) i have an array of objects from class `mainclass`:

```
myArray[0] = new mainclass(); 
myArray[1] = new mainclass();
//etc..
```

On runtime, i want to create a new `subclass` object, and set its reference to the one in `myArray[0]`, so that `myArray`is not changed, but myArray[0] then returns the new `subclass` object.

And i want to do this in the `mainclass`, so that the array **is not changed**, but the reference in the array points now to an other object (the new `subclass` object). In fact i want to do something like

```
this = new subclass();
```

in a method in `mainClass`

```
mainClass.prototype.changeType = function(){
 this = new subclass();
}
```

which of course doesnt work because you cant assign value to `this`.

Comment: What does the array looks like ?

Comment: You can't assign to the `this` keyword

Comment: So you have an array of `mainclass` and want to change that to an array of `subclass`?

Comment: You can't replace a "new" with another "new". Javascript is not as powerful as C, sorry :-|

Comment: @schroffl i basically want the references in the array pointing to other objects than before

Comment: @Lucker10 That's what I'm saying, Javascript has its limits.

Comment: Then you can just loop through the array and set the elements to an instance of `subclass`

Comment: @schroffl but i have no access to the array. I tried to clarify the question

Answer (score 1):

You could "simulate" pointers if you are ready to access your objects through indexes. As you can see below, whatever object reference is at index 0, it remains available :

```
function Person (name) { this.name = name; };
Person.prototype.whoami = function () { return this.name };
memory = [];
memory.push(new Person("Hillary Clinton"));
memory[0].whoami(); // "Hillary Clinton"
memory[0] = new Person("Donald Trump");
memory[0].whoami(); // "Donald Trump"
```

Good luck though... x-D

Comment: I dont want to change the array, but the references stored point to other objects than before..

Comment: @Lucker10 If you always access an object through its index, replacing it with another should be harmless.

Comment: yeah.. in C it would work easy. I thought maybe JS is so hacky that you can set an objects reference by (new mainclass).setReference(..) or something

Comment: @Lucker10 As far as I know, there is no such possibility.

Comment: @Lucker10 Javascript is not design to perform this kind of stuff, and that's fine. If you really need to touch the memory you can still choose another tool like C. Otherwise there are plenty of ways to bypass your problem while keeping a clean and elegant code :-)

Comment: but no way without accessing the array, or not?

Comment: Read my previous previous comment again : no x-)